# Can't invoke remove() method on a list of Strings in groovy

Tags: arraylist, groovy

I am trying to remove a String at a certain index in my list of Strings however I can't seem to invoke the list.remove() method in groovy.

```
public List getCassetteTypes(socket, numOfSlots){
 //get the cassettes layout
 sendCommand(socket, 'syst:layout? ')

 String systLayoutStr = readCommand(socket)
 //this String looks like: '1 ABC, 2 DEF, 3 SPN, ....'
    List listOfCassetteTypes = new ArrayList<String>()
 //I split the String at ',' because for each cassetteName, I want to remove the number before it
    listOfCassetteTypes = systLayoutStr.split(',')


    for(int i = 0; i < numOfSlots; i++){
      //remove any white spaces
        listOfCassetteTypes[i] = listOfCassetteTypes[i].trim()
      //remove the numerical value
        listOfCassetteTypes[i] = listOfCassetteTypes[i].replace((i + 1) + ' ', '')
        /* if the cassette name is 'SPN', 
      I want to remove it and append '-EXT' to the cassetteName before it,
      because 'SPN' means the previous slot is extended, 
      'SPN' itself isn't a cassette */
        if(listOfCassetteTypes[i].equalsIgnoreCase('spn')){
            listOfCassetteTypes[i - 1] = listOfCassetteTypes[i - 1].concat('-EXT')
   //this is what is not working for me, everything else is fine.
   listOfCassetteTypes = listOfCassetteTypes.remove(i)
        }
    }
    return listOfCassetteTypes
}
```

I've tried several different ways but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of ArrayList.remove in the doc? It's the element removed, not the list. Also, after fixing this, make sure you avoid advancing the index if you've removed an element, because after removing the element, the current index is already the next element.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I did not notice that, I thought remove() returns the new list with the element removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manipulating the list, you could process each entry in a pair with it's successor...  I believe this does what you're after?

```
def layoutStr = '1 ABC, 2 DEF, 3 SPN, 4 GHI'

def splitted = layoutStr.split(',')
    *.trim()                        // remove white space from all the entries (note *)
    *.dropWhile { it ==~ /[0-9 ]/ } // drop until you hit a char that isn't a number or space
    .collate(2, 1, true)            // group them with the next element in the list
    .findAll { it[0] != 'SPN' }     // if a group starts with SPN, drop it
    .collect { 
        // If the successor is SPN add -EXT, otherwise, just return the element
        it[1] == 'SPN' ? "${it[0]}-EXT" : it[0]
    }

assert splitted == ['ABC', 'DEF-EXT', 'GHI']
```

#### Followup question

To just get the numbers of the ones *not* `SPN`:

```
def layoutStr = '1 ABC, 2 DEF, 3 SPN, 4 GHI'

def splitted = layoutStr.split(',')
    *.trim()                                       // remove white space from all the entries (note *)
    *.split(/\s+/)                                 // Split all the entries on whitespace
    .findResults { it[1] == 'SPN' ? null : it[0] } // Only keep those that don't have SPN
```

Note that this is a list of Strings, not Integers...  If you need integers then:

```
    .findResults { it[1] == 'SPN' ? null : it[0] as Integer }
```

Comment: This did what I wanted!

Comment: on the other hand how would I only collect the numbers for the Strings that are not 'SPN' ?

Comment: Is that another question I hear?   Updated answer

Comment: 1 more follow-up question, what if I want to drop the sequence 'SPN' and don't want to add '-EXT' to the predecessor. In other words, from the sequence in the question what if I just want ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']

Comment: Remove code from the collate down and replace with `.findAll { it != 'SPN' }`